# Как отпустить файл, после создания переменной типа Image?

Tags: c#, .net, графика

Создаю переменную типа Image из картинки и после этого хочу удалить эту картинку физически и перезаписать изменённой картинкой из переменной, но ругается, что файл занят... подскажите, как мне отпустить файл? Пробовал вызывать dispose, но не помогло.

Собственно код:

```
  Image img=Image.FromFile(nonJpg);
        img.Save(newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        if (File.Exists(newFileName))
         {
          img.Dispose()
          File.Delete(nonJpg);
          File.Move(newFileName, newFileName.Replace("!_!", ""));
        }
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: @VladD, добавил.

Comment: `using (Image img=Image.FromFile(nonJpg)) { img.Save...; }`

Comment: @Igor, т.е картинка не грузится в память, а переменная дергает непосредственно файл?

Comment: А? Картинка грузится в память, файл `nonJpg` остается захваченным. А `using` вызывает `img.Dispose`, который отпускает файл.

Comment: @iluxa1810: А где у вас `Dispose`?

Comment: @Igor, хм... Если она грузится в память, то почему фабричный метод сам не отпускает файл и нужно диспозить весь объект?

Comment: @VladD, был перед Delete, но мне он не помог.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Хм, не люблю такие ответы, но: "так работает библиотечный класс".

Comment: @iluxa1810: Странно, должно было работать. Напишите код с `Dispose` тоже в вопросе, если можно.

Comment: @VladD, написал. А если я хочу оставить в памяти переменную, но хочу, что бы файл был отпущен, мне нужно из Потока картинку грузить, который потом задиспозить=> имеем свободный файл и картинку в переменной?

Comment: не смог воспроизвести. Ваш код работает. Возможно что-то еще лочит этот файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, там всё сложно: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814675.
`Image` требует, чтобы `Stream`, который он открывает на файл, существовал и не был закрыт. А незакрытый стрим означает невозможность операцией с файлом.

Скопирую обходной манёвр из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8701772/276994)

```
Image img;
using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(nonJpg))
    img = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
```

Должно работать также решение с кэшированием `MemoryStream`'е:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var fs = File.Open(nonJpg))
    fs.Copy(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: А если в MemoryStream заталкать, то это по сути решит все мои проблемы?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Так по идее тоже должно работать, `Image.FromStream`.

Comment: "заталкать" - проверочное слово "затАлкивать"?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Написал вариант со стримом (обратите внимание на `Seek`).