# Как правильно освободить Image

Tags: c#, изображения

Данный код кропает картинку по нижней части. Сохраненять в файл с тем же названием не дает из-за ошибки использования файла. Поэтому я создал временный файл с расширением `tmp`. Проблема возникает при удалении - из-за того что ресурс **fileName** занят. Как его правильно его освободить?

```
byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName); // для чтения
            FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(fileName+".tmp"); //  для записи
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {

                    using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
                    {
                        Image tmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(fileName));

                        imageFactory.Load(inStream)  // грузим картинку
                                    .Crop(new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height - 62))
                                    .Save(outStream); // сохраняем в поток
                        outStream.WriteTo(fs); // записываем в файл
                        outStream.Close();     // не забываем закрывать потоки ввода-вывода
                    }
                    inStream.Close(); // не забываем закрывать потоки ввода-вывода
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
            File.Delete(fileName);
            File.Move(fileName+".tmp", fileName);
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616496/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем так много всего, если это простой Crop. Попробуйте так:

```
string fileName = "2.png";
byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName); // для чтения
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) //  для записи
{
  using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
  {
    ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(true);
    var tmp = Image.FromStream(fs);

    var cropImg = imageFactory.Load(inStream).Crop(new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height - 300));

    inStream.Position = 0;
    cropImg.Save(inStream);
    fs.Position = 0;

    inStream.CopyTo(fs);
  }
}
```

Я бы ещё проще сделал:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string fileName = "5.png";
  byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
  using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
  {
    ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(true);
    var tmp = Image.FromStream(fs);

    var cropImg = imageFactory.Load(photoBytes).Crop(new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height - 300));
    fs.Position = 0;
    cropImg.Save(fs);
  }
}
```